# how can i plot a gini curve?

Tags: unbalanced-classes, roc, gini, credit-scoring

i am using a scoring metric as below: (gini)

```
def gini(solution, submission):                                                 
    df = sorted(zip(solution, submission),    
            key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    random = [float(i+1)/float(len(df)) for i in range(len(df))]                
    totalPos = np.sum([x[0] for x in df])                                       
    cumPosFound = np.cumsum([x[0] for x in df])                                     
    Lorentz = [float(x)/totalPos for x in cumPosFound]                          
    Gini = [l - r for l, r in zip(Lorentz, random)]                             
    return np.sum(Gini)                                                         


def normalized_gini(solution, submission):                                      
    normalized_gini = gini(solution, submission)/gini(solution, solution)       
    return normalized_gini   




param_grid =    { 
                  'model__learning_rate': [0.01,0.005,0.001],
                 
                  }

gini_scorer = make_scorer(normalized_gini, greater_is_better = True)

# Initialize Grid Search Modelg
model = GridSearchCV(estimator  =  XGBClassifier(),param_grid = param_grid,scoring = gini_scorer,
                                 verbose= 1,iid= True,
                                     refit = True,cv  = 3)
```

however as you do with roc-auc (compare predictions vs actual) and plot this how can i plot a gini curve of prediction vs actual?

Comment: ROC analysis requires a binary classification (true/false, yes/no, positive/negative, etc). Is this the case with your problem?

Comment: yes i am trying to predict loan default so yes or no